# is it possible to stream the postgresql dump

Tags: postgresql

I am using this command to backup the postgresql 13 database right now:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/pg_dump -v -h dba.google.com \
-U postgres -p 5432 -d dict \
--exclude-table-data=article_content \
--exclude-table-data=article \
-f /Users/dolphin/backup/dict-$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S').sql
```

but now I found a problem that the pg_dump did not dump for stream, the dump the remote database in memory, when complete, write the dump data into the disk. the problem is that when the remote database is large and the memory is not enough for the dump. is it possible to make the pg_dump work like a stream?

Comment: The `COPY` data will be streamed, and the dump file will grow as the dump proceeds. Perhaps you are experiencing a lock.